# convert bash script that accepts argument to zsh script

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a bash script that uses `hub` to create `pull-requests` easily. In bash it works fine, I just type `gpr <base_branch>` and does the logic in the code.

```
# git pr
function gpr() {
    # exit if no base branch supplied
    if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
        echo "No base branch supplied. Exiting"
        return
    fi

    if [[ ! $2 ]]; then
        echo "Creating pull-request"
        echo "No pull-request message set."
        read -p "Do you want to use the last commit message as pull-request message. Y or N? " choice
        if [[ $choice =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
            # Use last commit message
            COMMIT=$(git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s)
            echo "Using last commit message: $COMMIT"
            MESSAGE="-m '$COMMIT'"
        else
            # Use own message
            read -p "Enter message: " message
            MESSAGE=-"m '$message'"
        fi
    fi
    COMMAND="hub pull-request -b $1 $MESSAGE"
    echo "Creating pull-request against $1 branch with message: $MESSAGE"
    eval $COMMAND
    echo "Pull-request created successfully"
}
```

Which in the end will result to `hub pull-request -b <base_branch> -m <pull-request message or last commit message>`

But how do I convert this to `zsh`?

I tried pasting the code to `.zshrc` but it seems to be not working. I get the following when running `gpr <base_branch>`

```
gpr develop
Creating pull-request
No pull-request message set.
gpr:read:10: -p: no coprocess
gpr:read:18: -p: no coprocess
Creating pull-request against develop branch with message: -m ''
And vim appears
```

In bash the process goes like this

```
gpr develop
Creating pull-request
No pull-request message set.
Do you want to use the last commit message as pull-request message. Y or N? y
Using last commit message: [UIUX-x] Commit message
Creating pull-request against develop branch with message: -m '[UIUX-x] Commit message'
https://github.com/<author>/<repo>/pull/<num>
Pull-request created successfully
```

Comment: Instead of a shell function, how about a script in `~/bin/` or whatever (just set your `PATH` right) with a shebang pointing to `bash`?

Comment: Uhh, I'm not quite sure how to achieve that. I'm also doing this in `wsl` so it's easier for me to just add my own function to `zsh`.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/261591/how-to-create-and-run-bash-shell-scripts-on-windows-10/) it might work in WSL. (1) Write your code to a file `gpr` without lines: `function ...` and the last `}`. (2) Make the very first line a shebang: `#!/bin/bash`. (3) Make the file executable: `chmod +x gpr`. (4) Move the file to `~/bin` directory. (5) [Add `~/bin` path to `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/108618) unless it's already there. Then `gpr` will be handled by `bash` even in `zsh`. This is not an answer; it may solve your problem but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that zsh's `read` function takes different options than bash's. In bash, `read -p` specifies a prompt; in zsh, it says to read from a coprocess (which doesn't exist). You need to switch to the zsh syntax, which puts the prompt after the variable to read (delimited by a question mark):

```
read "choice?Do you want to use the last commit message as pull-request message. Y or N? "
...
read -p "message?Enter message: "
```

Also, I'd make two other recommendations (for both bash and zsh): first, use lowercase or mixed-case variable names; there are a large number of all-caps variable names with special meaning to the shell, system, etc (and they're not the same between bash and zsh), and it's way to easy to accidentally re-use one of them with weird consequences.

Second, building the command in a variable and then `eval`ing it is *not* safe (in either bash or zsh). Either [use an array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time), or just put the message (and *just* the message) in a variable and execute the command directly:

```
if ...
    message=$commit
else ...
    read message
fi

echo "Creating pull-request against $1 branch with message: $message"
hub pull-request -b "$1" -m "$message"
```